# Serializable FSharp object exception

Tags: serialization, f#

I have an F# class that must be serialized.

To show my problem I made it bulk:

```
[<Serializable>]
type TestValidator(min) =
    let Test value = 
        min < value
```

When I want to serialize/deserialize this I get the following error message:
*Binary stream '0' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. Possible causes are invalid stream or object version change between serialization and deserialization.*

My C# sample code to serialize:

```cs
var test = new Validator.TestValidator(0);
var ser = CodeHelper.ByteUtils.BinarySerializeObject(test);
var deser = CodeHelper.ByteUtils.BinaryDeSerializeObject(ser.Generic);
```

CodeHelper.ByteUtils.BinarySerializeObject:

```cs
   public static DetailedBoolObjectRet<byte[]> BinarySerializeObject(object input)
    {
        try
        {
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(ms, input);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[ms.Length];
            ms.Position = 0;
            ms.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            return new DetailedBoolObjectRet<byte[]>(bytes, true);
        }
        catch (System.Exception exc)
        {
            Debug.Assert(false, exc.Message);
            return new DetailedBoolObjectRet<byte[]>(null, false, exc.Message);
        }
    }

 public static DetailedBoolObjectRet<object> BinaryDeSerializeObject(byte[] input)
    {
        try
        {
            var ms = new MemoryStream(input);
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            var deserialized = formatter.Deserialize(ms);

            return new DetailedBoolObjectRet<object>(deserialized, true);
        }
        catch (System.Exception exc)
        {
            Debug.Assert(false, exc.Message);
            return new DetailedBoolObjectRet<object>(null, false, exc.Message);
        }
    }
```

What could be the problem with serializing?

Comment: It is very similar to [Deserialization not working on MemoryStream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228850/deserialization-not-working-on-memorystream)

Comment: May be, but it does not help, the exception is the same

Comment: Before someone asks: IsSerializable returns true in case of my class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just threw together a test

```
open System
open System.IO
open System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary

[<Serializable>]
type TestValidator(min) =
    let Test value = 
        min < value


let test = new TestValidator(0)
let ms = new MemoryStream()
let formatter = new BinaryFormatter()
formatter.Serialize(ms, test)
let bytes = Array.init (int ms.Length) (fun i -> byte 0x00)
ms.Position <- int64 0
ms.Read(bytes,0,int ms.Length)

let des =
    let ms = new MemoryStream(bytes)
    let formatter = new BinaryFormatter()
    formatter.Deserialize(ms) :?> TestValidator
```

Seems to work fine... Perhaps there's a problem with "DetailedBoolObjectRet"? The exception you're getting you can reproduce by trying to deserialize an array of 0x00.

EDIT:

If your problem is strictly with C# then try

```
[<Serializable>]
type TestValidator(min:int) =
    let Test value = 
        min < value
```

Though maybe that's not what you're after...

Comment: DetailedBoolObjectRet is nothing more than a simple class that returns the return value itself, a bool of success/unsuccess of process and string to return exception's string. So, my serializer - written in CSharp - can't deserialize my FSharp object.

Comment: Thx for your help. The 'strict' type definition helped me, but anyway it leads me to a new problem, cause by this way I can't have a general 'validator' class for any type of number. But thanks, anyway really kind from you to help me.